# Why was trench so thin if they knew Wights can't pass it?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the latest *Game of Thrones* episode (S08E03), it was shown that a trench was set on fire to prevent Wights from climbing the wall.

If they knew, they could build a wide trench to stop the Wights and could have killed all the stationary ones using dragons.

Comment: I doubt they ever meant it to stop the Dead. The ditch was meant to slow them down, which it did. The ditch was there as a, well last-ditch defense. If the dead managed to rout their forces in front of the Ditch, no ditches or walls would keep them out. Their best hope was to stall the dead long enough for survivors to retreat (With Unsullied covering them) and regroup once within the walls.

Comment: It was pretty wide to be honest. This isn't the real world we're talking about here. They don't have bulldozers and heavy machinery. Not did they have time. What did you expect, a 100m wide trench?

Comment: @Aegon "last-**ditch** defence" I'm cackling!!

Comment: @Möoz rather than seating in a room, entitling Brienne of Tarth as a knight, they could have created a trench 100m wide.

Comment: @Kaushal28 spoken like a person who's never had to dig a trench. :).  I'm teasing, but it really is time consuming to dig with shovels.

Comment: Why wasn't their army bigger? Why didn't Theon bring more arrows? Why didn't they drench the battlefield with tar so they could set it on fire when the dead come? They prepared as time allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Time and manpower were certainly factors. It takes a lot of time to dig a ditch, especially if the ground is frozen (and it is winter in the episode). You would also need more firewood to fill a wider trench - and remember that freshly felled trees don't make for very good firewood, unless there has been an extensive drought to dry out the wood. I imagine that basically all the stored firewood in Winterfell was used to fill the trenches.

As for using dragons to kill the stationary wights, that was done, but Dany and Jon chose to hunt the undead dragon rather than continue to do so - probably in an attempt to kill the Night King, who was riding that dragon at least some of the time. Also remember that dragons aren't invulnerable. The Night King killed and turned one, and another was nearly killed by a ballista in an earlier episode when Dany attacked a Lannister supply train. This suggests that using dragons in care should be done with care - more hit and run than steady attacks.

Comment: This is the show being daft but in the next episode they appear to be using lots of wood for only ~8 bodies and considering how many died that's a lot of wood... [see image](https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2019/05/courtesy-of-hbo-1.jpg).

Comment: Well, maybe the size of the ditch was more of a limiting factor than the supply of firewood. It is VERY hard to dig frozen ground.

Comment: To further your man power argument, you also don't want to exhaust your forces digging a giant trench into the frozen ground a couple hours before they fight a tireless foe.

Comment: Corpse cremation actually has pretty high [fuel requirements](https://www.quora.com/How-much-energy-is-required-for-a-human-cremation) from what I can tell.  tl;dr, 100kg of wood per body.

Comment: Wights might well be drier than fresh corpses. They sure look it.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen OK, so only 50kg of wood per corpse.  That's still a lot of wood.

Comment: You wouldn't need full cremation - just enough damage to render the wights immobile (or nearly so). Maybe 5 kg of wood per wight, on average? For a thousand wights, that comes to 5,000 kg or roughly 10 cubic metres - well within the realm of possibility.

Comment: @Klaus how many wights have you burned that you know it takes 1/10th of the cremation fuel to render them immobile? Lol. Also there were a lot more than 1000 wights

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of logistical problems to your question. Not sure there's a stated in-universe answer so we have to apply logic instead.

1. how many shovels do they have to equip diggers? Do diggers without tools help enough to matter?  Even improvised tools will slow the pace considerably.
2. what happens to diggers digging (and tired) if the wights show up while they're working?
3. the ditch wasn't the barrier, the fire was. How much fuel can they supply to create continuous flame along the whole trench, that also burns large and long enough to matter?  Fuel doesn't burn forever.
4. To be clear, you're talking about 100m wide and in a circle all the way around Winterfell. For easy numbers, let's say you want to place the trench 1/2 mile from the center of Winterfell (I'm not counting pixels to figure out how far away it actually was), that means you're digging a trench that's 3.14 miles long. I don't know how deep, let's call it 2m deep. That works out to about 5000 m x 100m x 2m, or about **1 million cubic meters of dirt and rocks**. Moved by hand.  In an unspecified amount of time.

   a. Digging in a bit more, I found modern shovels are non-standard, but a home improvement [Q&A site](https://www.justanswer.com/home-improvement/0teb6-hand-shovels-sand-equals-cubic-yard.html) (not a SE site, sadly) claims that a reasonable estimate is in the 135-162 shovel-fulls to fill a cubic yard, which for our purposes is close enough to a cubic meter.

   b.  If we err a little on the high side and say that's 160 shovel-fulls per cubic meter of material (not accounting for partial fillage and such due to rocks, roots, etc), that tells us it'd take **160 million shovel-fulls** to move enough dirt for a 100m-wide trench w/ a 1/2mile radius.

   c.  According to the [Canadian Center for Occupational Health and Safety](https://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/ergonomics/shovel.html) the recommended rate for sustained shoveling is around 15 scoops per minute, but you shouldn't go more than 15 minutes w/o a break.  I think given the situation, we can forego the safety concerns with going longer than 15 minutes w/o a break, and to make the math slightly easier let's say it's 16 scoops per person-minute of work.  That works out to 10 M person-minutes of work, or **166,666.67 person-hours**, not including breaks or the like.  Again, this assumes all your diggers have actual metal shovels that do not break.  We really are working off best-case numbers here.

   d.  According a [disturbingly well informed person on digging a grave](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-the-average-person-to-dig-a-six-foot-deep-grave) a standard grave (6'deep x 5' wide, x 6.5' long) should take 6 hours on optimal soil conditions, which the frozen north probably was not.

As with most real-world battles the "why didn't they X?" question almost always comes down to intel or logistics. And those are most often gated by time and manpower.